# Getting angular tags input to work

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

I am trying to implement [ng-tags-input](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput) to work within my website, so basically people need to input some tags by choosing tag(s) from a list of available tags persisted on database

**server:**

```
exports.list = function(req, res) {

  var query = req.query;
  mongoose.set('debug', true);

  Tag
    .find({
      'text': new RegExp(query.text, 'i')
    })
    .sort({
      created: -1
    })
    .select('text')
    .exec(function(err, tags) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(400).send({
          message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        });
      } else {
        console.log('Tags: ', tags);
        res.json(tags);
      }
    });
};
```

**angular controller:**

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('contests')
    .controller('ContestsAddController', ContestsAddController);

  ContestsAddController.$inject = [
    '$scope',
    '$state',
    '$location',
    'Tag'
  ];

  function ContestsAddController(
    $scope,
    $state,
    $location,
    Tag
  ) {
    var vm = this;

    /** Properties */
    vm.tags = [];

    /** Methods */
    vm.loadTags = loadTags;

    function loadTags(query) {
      return Tag.load();
    }
  }
}());
```

**view:**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label">With tags </label>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <tags-input ng-model="vm.tags" add-from-autocomplete-only="true">
      <auto-complete source="vm.loadTags($query)" debounce-delay="500" load-on-empty="true"></auto-complete>
    </tags-input>
  </div>
</div>
```

**angular service:**

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('tags')
    .factory('Tag', Tag);

  Tag.$inject = [
    '$http',
    '$q',
    '$timeout',
    'Authentication',
    'Shuttle',
    'CONST'
  ];

  function Tag(
    $http,
    $q,
    $timeout,
    Authentication,
    Shuttle,
    CONST
  ) {

    var service = {
      getTags: getTags,
      load: load
    };
    var _this = this;

    return service;

    // SCOPE FUNCTIONS
    function getTags(query) {
      return Shuttle.get(CONST.EP_TAGS, query, {}, 1000, {
        Authorization: 'JWT ' + Authentication.token
      });
    }

    function load() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      deferred.resolve(this.getTags({}));
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
}());
```

**Tag.load() response**

```
[  
  {  
    "_id":"579ecc5fca552b6e89094415",
    "text":"Comedian"
  },
  {  
    "_id":"579ecc5aca552b6e89094414",
    "text":"Cardist"
  },
  {  
    "_id":"579ecc56ca552b6e89094413",
    "text":"Magician"
  },
  {  
    "_id":"579ecc4bca552b6e89094412",
    "text":"Actress"
  },
  {  
    "_id":"579ecc47ca552b6e89094411",
    "text":"Actor"
  },
  {  
    "_id":"579ecbecca552b6e89094410",
    "text":"Bassist"
  },
  {  
    "_id":"579ecbdfca552b6e8909440f",
    "text":"Guitarist"
  },
  {  
    "_id":"579ecbd9ca552b6e8909440e",
    "text":"Singer"
  },
  {  
    "_id":"579ecbc6ca552b6e8909440d",
    "text":"Dancer"
  }
]
```

The problems that i am facing is that when i typed 3 letters (which correctly triggered Tag.load() as expected, and returning above's response)

- it doesn't show any auto complete or tag suggestions
- it's immediately putting that 3 letters as a tag (picture below)
- the `console.log(vm.tags);` is not including the whole Tag object, just the `text` key value pair

[image]

is there something i missed?

i am using angular 1.5.0

**UPDATE**

I have added a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YmUkPHRlWpn3Q14eWzg9?p=preview) although with some modifications, but it is working just fine there, though it still doesn't work in my app, is it angular version?

One more thing i forgot to mention, the one's in mine is not showing the dropdown as i typed.

**UPDATE #2**
I updated the plunker using angular 1.5.0 which is the one i am using, and its working, so its not angular version.

Comment: Could you provide a Plunker showing your problem? You can use [this template](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:93P2qxOjYmlcYSqDmo39).

Comment: @MichaelBenford added a plunker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying out a few things, i finally got it working by doing this

I reserved the `Tag.getTags` response object in a variable and call it on load rather than calling it every time user typed (or using the load-on-focus and or load-on-empty parameters) and using the filter method based on [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/LfBMgU4yPNFMipOhLURM) example

**controller**

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('contests')
    .controller('ContestsAddController', ContestsAddController);

  ContestsAddController.$inject = [
    '$scope',
    '$state',
    '$location',
    'Tag',
    'toaster',
    'lodash'
  ];

  function ContestsAddController(
    $scope,
    $state,
    $location,
    Tag,
    toaster,
    lodash
  ) {
    var vm = this;

    /** Properties */
    vm.tagList = [];
    vm.tags = [];

    /** Methods */
    vm.loadTags = loadTags;

    function loadTags($query) {
      return vm.tagList.filter(function(tag) {
        return tag.text.toLowerCase().indexOf($query.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
      });
    }

    activate();

    function activate() {
      return _getTagList();
    }

    function _getTagList() {
      Tag
        .getTags()
        .then(function(response) {
          vm.tagList = response.data;
          return vm.tagList;
        });
    }
  }
}());
```

**view** (dont know if this is related)

```
<tags-input ng-model="vm.tags" display-property="text" add-from-autocomplete-only="true" text="text">
  <auto-complete source="vm.loadTags($query)" debounce-delay="500"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```